# How to make sqlite in-memory db join query as fast as MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, perl, sqlite, in-memory-database

I have a very complex sql query - the logic is simple, but I need to join 17 tables (each as 10-20 fields and 100 to 1 million records) so there're a lot of (LEFT) JOINs and WHERE clauses.

```
SELECT table1.column_A
       table2.column_B
       table3.column_C
       table4.column_D
       ....
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_a = table2.column_b
JOIN table3 ON table3.column_c = table1.column_d
LEFT JOIN table4.column_e = table3.column_f
    AND LENGTH(table4.column_g) > 6 AND (table4.column_h IN (123,234))
LEFT JOIN ....
....
WHERE table1.column_i = 21 
    AND (table1.column_j IS NULL OR DATE(table1.column_k) <> DATE(table1.column_l))
```

The above query only takes 5 seconds to run in MySQL. But when I run it in sqlite in-memory db (using Perl on Linux), it takes about 20 min. This is still acceptable.

When I add a ORDER BY clause (I do need this), the execution time increases dramatically.

```
ORDER BY table1.column_m, table6.column_n, table7.column_o IS NULL;
```

It'll take 40 seconds in MySQL. In sqlite in-memory db (using Perl on Linux), I waited for over an hour, but it still didn't finish.

What kind of tuning do I need to do to make the query faster? My threshold is within 1 hour.

The reason I'm making it an in-memory db is that I receive SQL generated normalized data but we need to load data into a non-SQL db in the end, so I don't want to create a intermediate SQL db just for data loading - that makes the code ugly and increases maintenance complexity. Plus, the current timing issue I'm facing is just a one-time thing. In the future on a daily basis, the data volume we receive will be much much smaller (less than 1% of what I have today)

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: It might be hard to troubleshoot your performance problem without seeing the structure of your tables and the exact query you're running. Since you're working with a lot of tables, I would recommend creating a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a similar query using just a few test tables. Then you can show the table definitions you used in MySQL and SQLite, and the timings for each.

Comment: Are the MySQL tables in memory (`ENGINE = MEMORY`) or are they standard ones? Don't forget sorting your results in Perl may be faster

Comment: MySQL tables are standard ones (on Windows), while sqlite are in-memory ones on Linux.

Comment: The database may be in-memory, but that does not mean the disk does not come in to play, especially when you are joining a large number of large tables. Buy a large enough SSD and upgrade memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your ORDER BY clause is on columns from 3 different tables.  No amount of query optimization or index creation is going to change the fact that the DBMS must do an external sort, after (or as) the result set is produced.  If you've constrained the amount of memory that SQLite can use (I'm not a SQLite expert, but I assume this is at least possible, if not required), then that could be the cause (e.g. it's going through some incredible machinations to get the job done within its limits).  Or it's just hung.  What's the CPU utilization for that hour you were waiting?  What about I/O (is it thrashing because there was no limit on the amount of memory SQLite can use, as Sinan alluded to)?

Answer (score -3):

To make your query faster , you need to do some changes in one of the following :

- method of writing query
- Database table structure
- making proper indexes

And all this you can find at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=273952